# how to get data to the other component when you selected a specific row

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material-table

I'm trying to get the data when i'm selecting specific row using mat-table

Here the example of what i'm going to do, by getting DR20220000013 will pass to the Delivery Receipt#

[image: HERE'S THE EXAMPLE]

> .HTML

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="DeliveryReceipt">

<ng-container matColumnDef="transactionType">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Transaction #</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.transactionType}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
(click)="selectedRow(row)"></mat-row>
          </mat-table>
```

> .TS

```
selectedRow(row){
  console.log('selectedRow', row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to share data between components, input binding, services you name it... https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

But I'm going out on a limb here and taking a guess what could work. The overlying `mat-table` where you select the row appears to be a dialog modal.

The modal is probably opened somewhere from the parent component, most likely where `Delivery Receipt#` is too?

So when we open the modal, we will subscribe to the modal. We will start listening to the value emitted by the modal when the modal closes (i.e when user does `selectedRow()` we close modal and return value). That return value is then catched and fed to `Delivery Receipt#`.

In parent

```js
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  deliveryReciept: any; 

  // here we open the modal, and pass in data for mat-table
  // your modal name is probably different
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeliveryRecieptDialog, { 
      width: '250px',
      data: {DeliveryReceipt: this.DeliveryReceipt, selectedReceipt: null},
    });

    // here we listen to what user selected
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.deliveryReciept = result.selectedReceipt;
    });
  }
```

In the modal:

```js
  DeliveryReceipt: any;
  selectedReceipt: any;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeliveryRecieptDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) {

  this.DeliveryReceipt = data.DeliveryReceipt;
  this.selectedReceipt = data.selectedReceipt;
}

selectedRow(row){
  console.log('selectedRow', row);
  this.selectedReceipt = row
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

The above is an explanation how to return data from modal and then use return data where it was opened from, you may have to change the previous code for it to actually work in your project.

Comment: "So when we open the modal, we will subscribe to the modal. We will start listening to the value emitted by the modal when the modal closes (i.e when user does selectedRow() we close modal and return value). That return value is then catched and fed to Delivery Receipt#."

this is want i wanted to do.  i tried your code but its error.  btw, the data im using is DTO.

Comment: Perhaps a with a simpler demo you can see how data is passed and returned. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples#dialog-overview

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a shared service

**Service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransactionService {
  transactionCode = '';
}
```

**Component with table**

```
constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {};

selectedRow(row){
  this.transactionService.transactionCode = row;
}
```

**Any other component that needs the data**

```
constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {};

get transactionCode() {
   return this.transactionService.transactionCode;
}

someMethod() {
  console.log(this.transactionCode);
}
```

```html
<p>{{ transactionCode }}</p>
```

Comment: That seems completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: i got this when i select the table [object Object]